# How to get a tag which contains span text

Tags: python

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import re

text = """<td align="center" width="225" height="50" bgcolor="#2175bc" style="height:50px;display:block;font-family:'helvetica neue','helvetica','arial',sans-serif;font-size:17px;border:solid 1px #2175bc;border-radius:6px;">
                    <a href="https://trg/portal" target="_blank" style="color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;line-height:50px;width:100%;display:inline-block;">
                    <span style="color:#ffffff;line-height:50px;">View Sport<span></span></span></a>
                </td>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
              
span_text = soup.find("span", text=re.compile("View Sport|view this Sport", re.IGNORECASE))
print(span_text)
```

Is there any solution to get "https://trg/portal" by the span text "View Sport" of a tag.

Required solution: https://trg/portal

Comment: from the `span_text` tag you can use `previous_sibling`, right?

Comment: @cards It's not a sibling, it's the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a selector that finds `span` that's a child of `a`. Then use `.parent` to get the containing `a` element.

```
spans = soup.select("a > span", text=re.compile("View Sport|view this Sport", re.IGNORECASE))
links = [span.parent['href'] for span in spans]
```

Comment: Changed it to `['href']`, that works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Create your [own function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) to pass to the `find` method.

```
def is_myspan(tag) -> bool:    
     return tag.name == 'span' and re.search("View Sport|view this Sport", tag.getText(strip=True), re.I)

span_text = soup.find(is_myspan)
print(span_text.parent['href'])
```